# Evaluate Big O loop worst case and condition statements

Tags: asymptotics, computational-complexity

Understanding big O, worst case in a loop. Im supposed to count assignation and comparisons, I dont get why?

The other doubt I have is if the worst case is seeing/evaluated to infinity or for all the executions that are in agreement with the conditon?

Here the comparison is in function of the **for** loop, which is done n times so comparisons are done n times as well. Since assignations are in function of comparisons, they are done n/2 times.
Multiplying them all together gives me (n+n/2) x (n+n/2) = (n^2)+3/2(n^2) = ***n^2***.

If I understood things correctly, I will multiply the two ***for*** loops or the inner requirements(assignments and comparisons), to get big O?

```
test void (char tab [50]){
   a = 0;
   for (i = 0; i<= tab.length()-1; i++){  <--n
       if(i % 2 == 1)                     <----------- n
           a = a - tab[i];                <----------- n/2 
   }
   for (j = 0; j <= tab.length()-1; i++){ <--n
       if(j % 2 == 0)                     <----------- n
           a = a - tab[j];                <----------- n/2
   }
}
```

Comment: If a for-loop is contained within another for-loop, you'd multiply them. Here they are separate and so you would add them. (also, your second loop contains i++, which should be j++?)

Comment: You don't have to multiply, but add, as the cycles go one after the other. But $O(n)+O(n)=O(n)$.

Comment: @DavidP you are right, thanks

Comment: @zkutch thanks for the input